# Why do developers lock word-length data during reads/writes in multithreaded code?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, locking, atomic

Specifically in unmanaged languages (e.g. C++, C), my understanding is that reads/writes of word-length data are atomic. If this is the case then why do people still lock (via mutex) word-length data during reads/writes in a multithreaded environment?

Comment: (Assuming your assumption about the atomicity of such operations is correct) Atomicity is only half the puzzle. The operations also need to be ordered to avoid races. (things like `std::atomic<int>` in C++11 not only guarantee atomicity of operations, but also impose order)

Answer (score 8):

Reads and writes may* be individually atomic, but read-modify-write sequences are not.

*That depends very much on the architecture and how you use it.

Comment: Also some single operations in higher languages (like the operation ++c, pun intended) are actually a combined read, inc, write in assembly.

Comment: @MarkusKull: not "some", but rather "all". Some compilers may be able to optimize them on some architectures, but you should not rely on atomicity unless the language standard says so (and it usually doesn't).

Answer (score 5):

An Intel x86 (or compatible) processor will do word-sized reads and writes atomically as long as the data is properly aligned (specifically, so the entire word is in the same cache line).

Two obvious problems with that though:

1. Incorrect alignment can break it
2. It's not portable -- a different CPU could break it as well

Less obviously, atomic operations can force a memory fence so operations happen in the correct order. For example, if I'm writing some data, then writing a status variable to tell another process that the data is now valid, it's not enough that each of those writes is atomic -- it's crucial that the "valid" status only be set *after* the data itself has actually been written. Without some sort of memory fence operation, the processor is free to rearrange writes so the status could be written before the data.

Answer (score 5):

It depends by what you mean by "atomic".  There is *not* any
guarantee in C++ that a read or a write to a variable actually
ends up in global memory where other threads can see it.

Comment: Except when you use C++11 atomic types.

Comment: +1 atomic has many different meanings and this is the core of OP's confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Because an assignment (what I assume you mean by read/write of data) in a language like C or C++ may still be multiple assembly instructions, and the thread can be preempted at any of them.

Comment: Even a single assembly instruction is not, in general, atomic WRT other processors.